# How to pass multiple selected check-box values in repeater C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, repeater

I am using Repeater control to display data from Database table in HTML table on ASPX page. There are also two link buttons `Approve` and `Reject`which are bind with Repeater method `ItemCommand`.

There is a checkbox in first column of each row. This will enable user to select multiple rows and perform Approve and Reject operation. Here is the code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="PendingRegRepeater" runat="server" OnItemCommand="PendingRegRepeater_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Select
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Customer Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Space ID
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Date
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Amount Paid
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Pin Code
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Payment Method
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Action
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustomerName") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SpaceID") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TransactionDate") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AmountPaid") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Pincode") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PaymentMethod") %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkApprove" CommandName="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RRID") %>' Text="Approve" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="true"></asp:LinkButton>
                                /
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkReject" CommandName="Reject" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RRID") %>' Text="Reject" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Font-Underline="true"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

But I am unable to think a way to handle when user selects multiple checkboxes and presses Approve or Reject button. The compiler won't allow me to set ID attribute of Check-box a dynamic value `<%# Eval("RRID") %>`. Please suggest to handle this situation. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The id of checkbox will be generated using the id you assigned to the checkbox. ASP.net generated will have unique id for each checkbox in the generated row.

*Html*

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="checkBoxID" />
```

*In code Behind*

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in PendingRegRepeater.Items)
{
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var checkBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("checkBoxID");
        checkBox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: and on server side how to check which check-boxes are selected?

Comment: Actually I need to associate <%# Eval("RRID") %> with each check-box because after user selects check-boxes I will be able to query with each selected check-box id or row id.

Comment: You can try adding custom attribute to checkbox like <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="checkBoxID" SomeAttr='<%# Eval("RRID") %>' /> and later accessing it like checkBox.Attributes["SomeAttr"].ToString()

Answer (score 2):

Just set each checkbox a static ID.  The actual ID object generated will be unique for each row.

You can then go through all of the rows and access that checkbox for each row:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeater.Items)
{
    var checkbox = item.FindControl("checkboxId") as CheckBox;
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to associate <%# Eval("RRID") %> with each check-box because after user selects check-boxes I will be able to query with each selected check-box id or row id.

Comment: @NidaSulheri But you already have access to all of the row information through the `RepeaterItem` object.  There's no need to embed the information in the `ID` property.

Answer (score 2):

Greate, clearly sample i've made for you:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPerson" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chCustomer" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("LastName") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In your C# code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptPerson.Items)
    {
        CheckBox c = item.Controls[1] as CheckBox;
        if (c.Checked)
            doSomething((item.Controls[3] as HiddenField).Value);
    }
}
```

You can breakpoint at the beggining of this method to check wehre are the controls of your repeater positioned. In this example the asp:HiddenField is at position 3 and the asp:checkBox is at position 1.

I very !!! recommand you to create a UserControl that composite together all the elements you need for one row with the required properties like: Checked, ID etc... and simply put that control in the repeater  section so it will generate all you need together for every row (include ID).